# Android Studio, pass to next page if one out of two text fields are filled

Tags: java, android, error-messaging

So I  basically want to know how would I  allow the user to proceed to the next page when they hit pay if either txtCode or StreetCode is filled, only one of these two needs to be filled in order to pass to the next page but how would i get that to work as currently they both must filled to pass to the next page.

```
    btnPay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPay);/** REFERENCE THE PAY BUTTON*/
    btnPay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {/** SETS ONCLICKLISTENER TO LISTEN FOR BUTTON CLICK*/
            /** REFERENCES ALL VARIABLE TO FIELDS IN LAYOUT */
             txtReg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtReg);
             txtCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCode);
             txtStreetName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtStreetName);

             dlCostTime = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.dlCostTime);



            if( txtReg.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            {
                txtReg.setError("required!");
            }
            if( txtCode.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            {
                txtCode.setError("required!");
            }
            if( txtStreetName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            {
                txtStreetName.setError("required!");
            }


            else{
                final Button btnPay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPay);

                btnPay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent payIntent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);// creates intent to open payment details
                        UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(payIntent);//Performs intent to open payment page
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: I think you must have heard of OR operator.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example or solution with the OR operator plz

Comment: "`||`" is called OR operator and what's your exact requirement? Is it compulsory for user just to fill one field or he can fill both as well in order to proceed?

Comment: The user only must enter the registration, they can either enter code or street name not both, only one, code or street name, then the user can pass to next activity

Comment: I have used | | before but not only with numbers.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code

```
if( txtReg.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
{
    txtReg.setError("required!");
}
if( txtCode.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
{
    txtCode.setError("required!");
}
if( txtStreetName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
{
    txtStreetName.setError("required!");
}


else{
    final Button btnPay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPay);

    btnPay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent payIntent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);// creates intent to open payment details
            UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(payIntent);//Performs intent to open payment page
        }
    });

}
```

with this

```
if( txtReg.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
    txtReg.setError("required!");
}else{

    if((txtCode.getText().toString().trim().equals("") && !txtStreetName.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) || 
            (!txtCode.getText().toString().trim().equals("") && txtStreetName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))){
        Intent payIntent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);// creates intent to open payment details
        UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(payIntent);//Performs intent to open payment page
    }else{
        //show message enter either code or street name not both
}
```

Comment: final Button btnPay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPay);

                btnPay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent payIntent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);// creates intent to open payment details
                        UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(payIntent);//Performs intent to open payment page
                    }
                });

            }

Comment: and it only asks for the registration then passed to the next page

Comment: Actually never mind it does work i didn't realise you replaced my intent to open activity in the last else statement, once i removed that it worked great, enter both street and code, doesn't work, enter none, doesn't work, enter only of them then passes to next activity, thank you.

Comment: Cool, happy to help you. You can accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: `AlertDialog dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this).create(); dlgAlert.setMessage("This is an alert with no consequence"); dlgAlert.setTitle("App Title"); dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null); dlgAlert.setCancelable(true); dlgAlert.show();`

Comment: Thank you very much :D, im fairly new to android studio as i am using to to create my final year project for university that due a week, just dont know some of the features for little thing so again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
 btnPay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPay);/** REFERENCE THE PAY BUTTON*/
    btnPay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {/** SETS ONCLICKLISTENER TO LISTEN FOR BUTTON CLICK*/
            /** REFERENCES ALL VARIABLE TO FIELDS IN LAYOUT */
            txtReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtReg);
            txtCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCode);
            txtStreetName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtStreetName);

            dlCostTime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dlCostTime);


            if (txtCode.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 || txtStreetName.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                final Button btnPay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPay);

                btnPay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent payIntent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);// creates intent to open payment details
                        UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(payIntent);//Performs intent to open payment page
                    }
                });
            } else if (txtStreetName.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                txtStreetName.setError("required!");
            } else if (txtReg.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                txtReg.setError("required!");
            } else if (txtCode.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                txtCode.setError("required!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you both for your help, Aravindraj I tried your code and it still passed user to next page even if i filled them both in, I am more inclined to use the OR operator stated by kunu, It would be a great help if anyone could give an example with the OR operator for txtcode and txtStreerName

Comment: Basically how do I use the OR operator for the Editext Fields